# Proxy setting for zope.testbrowser

Tags: python, django, proxy, mechanize, zope

In [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) we can set proxy like this:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_proxies({"http": "joe:password@myproxy.example.com:3128",
"ftp": "proxy.example.com",})
```

How do we do the same for [zope.testbrowser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testbrowser)?

Many thanks!

Comment: Format your question by using SO's markdown (or the editor toolbar) don't use HTML tags directly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zope.testbrowser` is a wrapper around mechanize, and you can reach the wrapped mechanize browser via the `mech_browser` attribute:

```
 browser.mech_browser.set_proxies(dict(
     http="joe:password@myproxy.example.com:3128",
     ftp="proxy.example.com",
 ))
```

Not tested, but the above should work.

Comment: It works as expected! Many thanks. Was not able to upvote since i don't have enough reputation yet :) .. (just created my account yesterday)

Comment: Ah, indeed! It's been a while since I had 0 points of reputation. ;-)